# JSON Data in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Hi I am developing one quizz app and the issue is, I have the following JSON Data, which is a respond from my WebService.

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "question": "tes!2t",
        "option1": "test",
        "option2": "test",
        "option3": "test",
        "option4": "test",
        "correct_answer": "test",
        "explanation": "test",
        "image": "test",
        "created_at": "2014-09-23 02:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2014-09-09 06:19:28"
    }
]
```

How can I display the Data **option1,option2,option3 and option4** in a TableViewCell.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 4;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell==nil)

    {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    }



    NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/quiz/public/questions";



    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:urlString:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    NSArray *array = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"questions"];



    questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];

    //choices = [[NSArray alloc] init];





    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {

        question = [[Questions alloc] initWithObject:dict];

        [questions addObject:question];

    }



    cell.textLabel.text = [choices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bold" size:12];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    int selectedRow = indexPath.row;



    NSString *filePathChoices = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"questions" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *JSONDataChoices = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:urlString
:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *jsonObjectChoices = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONDataChoices options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well, you study the documentation for NSJSONSerialization and study any of the hundreds of examples on the web.  Or you come here and get someone to do your homework for you and never learn anything.

Comment: And, BTW, two of the three answers are wrong.  I'll let you guess which ones.

Comment: Using NSArray answer is correct remain is wrong,is it?@HotLicks

Comment: Actually, all three answers are wrong, though they may appear to work for a time.

Comment: but some modifications on my code it's working @HotLicks,and moreover Stack overflow is best one to clarify issues,now my code is working fine,i am happy and confident thank you.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  Then study the docs for NSArray and NSDictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61384/discussion-between-gpr-and-hot-licks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hopefully it will works:

```
NSString *urlString = @"your URL";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;

jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
jsonDict11 = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"question"];
NSLog(@"array %@",jsonDict11);
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [jsonDict11 count]);
Questionscount=[jsonDict11 count];
self.QuestionsText.text=[jsonDict11 objectAtIndex:ii];
```

In TableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
NSArray *jsonDict1=[jsonObject valueForKey:@"option1"];
NSArray *jsonDict2=[jsonObject valueForKey:@"option2"];
NSArray *jsonDict3=[jsonObject valueForKey:@"option3"];
NSArray *jsonDict4=[jsonObject valueForKey:@"option4"];

  NSString *str1=[jsonDict1 objectAtIndex:ii];
  NSString *str2=[jsonDict2 objectAtIndex:ii];
  NSString *str3=[jsonDict3 objectAtIndex:ii];
  NSString *str4=[jsonDict4 objectAtIndex:ii];

 nameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:str1,str2,str3,str4,nil];
 cell.textLabel.text = [nameArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"question\":\"tes!2t\",\"option1\":\"test\",\"option2\":\"test\",\"option3\":\"test\",\"option4\":\"test\",\"correct_answer\":\"test\",\"explanation\":\"test\",\"image\":\"test\",\"created_at\":\"2014-09-23 02:00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-09-09 06:19:28\"}]";
```

Pass your json string ("jsonString")

```
NSData *aDataJson = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *aError = nil;
NSArray *aArrJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aDataJson options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &aError];
NSLog(@"%@",aArrJson);
NSLog(@"%@",[[aArrJson objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"question"]);
```